# jquery code is not changing a div's visibility property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple one field form to demonstrate this.  I have a div that is hidden and which serves as an error message.  If the firstname input field empty then I want to change the div's visibility to visible but my jquery code is not doing that and also any code below the jquery statement does not execute. So, the alert box never pops up. I'm changing the div's visibility with this: `$("#name_require").css("visibility", "visible");`

HTML code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700">

<script>
  function validateForm() {


    var firstname = document.forms["myform"]["firstname"].value;

    var errors = false;

    if (firstname == "") {

      errors = true;

      $("#name_require").css("visibility", "visible"); //This fails all the javascript below it does not execute and the alter box never pops up.

      alert('name field is empty');

    }


  }
</script>

<body>


  <div class="ss-form-container">
    <div class="ss-header-image-container">
      <div class="ss-header-image-image">
        <div class="ss-header-image-sizer"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="ss-form">
      <form id="ss-form" name="myform">
        <ol role="list" class="ss-question-list" style="padding-left: 0">
          <div class="ss-form-question errorbox-good" role="listitem">
            <div dir="ltr" class="ss-item ss-item-required ss-text">
              <div class="ss-form-entry">
                <label class="ss-q-item-label" for="entry_710276695">
                  <div class="ss-q-title">First name

                    <span class="ss-required-asterisk" aria-hidden="true">*</span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="ss-q-help ss-secondary-text" dir="ltr"></div>
                </label>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" value="" class="ss-q-short" id="entry_710276695" dir="auto">
                
                <div id="name_require" style="visibility:hidden;color:red;">This is a required question</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          
          <div class="ss-item ss-navigate">
            <input type="button" name="submit" value="Submit" id="ss-submit" class="jfk-button jfk-button-action " onclick="validateForm()">

          </div>
        </ol>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <br>

</body>
```

Comment: Asking about that specific issue should really not require all that CSS that you have shown. Please reduce such examples to the minimal code that reproduces the problem, and leave out unimportant stuff.

Comment: Where you have included jquery?

Comment: Assuming you did indeed include jQuery, there's no element with the name `lastname` and it errors out on that line as it's not defined.

Comment: And there are no elements with the names `age` or `phonenumber` either

Comment: and, after all - you don't need jquery for such small thing... do it in vanilla js...

Comment: @adeneo please look at the updated code. I have removed all that. thanks.  And I am using jquery in the following line: `$("#name_require").css("visibility", "visible");`

Comment: _“And I am using jquery in the following line”_ – the question wasn’t where you are _trying to use_ it, but where you embedded the library file.

Comment: Removing those lines and including jQuery, it works just fine -> **http://jsfiddle.net/e63k9gf4/**

Comment: @CBroe I just realized that too. I forgot to include the library file. thanks.

Comment: $("#name_require").css("visibility", "visible") = document.getElementById('name_require').style.visibility='visible';

Comment: And as others have noted, there's no need for jQuery for just one simple line, here you go -> **http://jsfiddle.net/e63k9gf4/1/**

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing `style="visibility:hidden;color:red;"` with `style="display:none;color:red;"` in DOM and `$("#name_require").css("visibility", "visible");` with `$("#name_require").toggle();` in your script.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: include link to Jquery library file in the HTML file.